# How do I make a material-ui select with a tooltip that doesn't make the select larger?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui select in react, built like so:

```
<TextField
        fullWidth
        select
        id={'area'}
        label={'Area'}
        value={DCA.area ? DCA.area : ''}
        variant={TEXT_FIELD_VARIANT_TYPE}
        onChange={(evt) => handleValueChange(evt, 'area')}
        >

        { Object.keys(dcaData[DCA.domain][DCA.category]).map(selectKey =>
                <Tooltip key={"Area_MenuItem_Tooltip_" + selectKey} title={dcaData[DCA.domain][DCA.category][selectKey]}  value={selectKey} >
                        <MenuItem  key={"Area_MenuItem_Tooltip_" + selectKey} value={selectKey} >{selectKey}</MenuItem>
                </Tooltip>
                            )}

</TextField>
```

This is functional.

The problem is there is an identical select next to it.  That select does not have a tooltip.  When you add the tooltip, it all works as expected... except when the select has been selected, the height of the textfield changes.

I have tried adding `style={{padding:'0px'}}` to the TextField, the Tooltop, and the MenuItem.  When added to the Tooltip or the MenuItem, it helps (but doesn't entirely fix the problem) but then the 'drop down' popup menu is also without padding and doesn't match the style of the other selects.

Is there something I can do to add the tooltip but keep the 'collapsed' / selected TextField from changing it's size?

Comment: Can you put your code in Codesandbox?